# Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported tkeclipse

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection, macos-high-sierra, tcltk

When executing tkeclipse or tktools, I get the following message:

```
/.../Eclipse/bin/x86_64_macosx/tkeclipse ; exit;
objc[18335]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.

/.../Eclipse/tcltk/x86_64_macosx/bin/wish8.5: line 2: 18335 Abort trap: 6 
"$(dirname $0)/../Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Wish.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish" "$@"

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I only get this message since I updated my Mac (currently version 10.13.4). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The solution I found was to execute the `xtkeclipse` and `xtktools` commands instead. You should have these executables since they come with the MacOS's eclipse.

They both rely on X11, if you don't have it installed you can download the installer here: https://www.xquartz.org

After the installation you need to logout and then log back in order to make the executables run correctly.
Hope it help.